# Draggable dot on rotatable div, dot following rotation after dragend

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to make dot that follows mouse cursor. It was all working, but when i rotated it a bit it all messed up, because bounding box has changed.

I was using this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation
(That's why i initially negated y, and than negated new value again)
[image]

I will need to read how far that dot is from center and it's angle (but related to the initial "0" rotation state)

I have to add something to rPX based on angle, but i don't know how to calculate it. Can anyone relate?
Inner div is only for creating center of coordinate system.
https://jsfiddle.net/jre86rdd/14/

```
var currentMousePosition = {
    x:0,
    y:0
}

var angle = Math.PI/6

document.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event){
    currentMousePosition.x = event.clientX;
    currentMousePosition.y = event.clientY;
    applyMovement(event)
})

function applyMovement(event){
    var rPX = event.clientX - getElementOffSetFromParentLeft(document.getElementById("light").parentNode) - 5;
    var rPY = -(event.clientY - getElementOffSetFromParentTop(document.getElementById("light").parentNode) - 5);
    var XinCircle = rPX*Math.cos(angle)-rPY*Math.sin(angle)
    var YinCircle = rPX*Math.sin(angle)+rPY*Math.cos(angle)

    if(XinCircle > -70 && XinCircle < 70)
    document.getElementById("light").style.left = XinCircle + "px";
    if(rPY > -70 && rPY < 70)
    document.getElementById("light").style.top = -YinCircle + "px";
    //console.log(rPX + " X " + XinCircle )
    //console.log(rPY + " Y " + YinCircle )
}

var getElementOffSetFromParentLeft = function (htmlElement) {
        var parentRect = htmlElement.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect(),
            bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(parentRect.left)
        //I need to add something here, it's 75 for 30, i have no idea how i have calculated it
       return parentRect.left - bodyRect.left + 75;
}
var getElementOffSetFromParentTop = function (htmlElement) {
        var parentRect = htmlElement.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect(),
            bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
        return parentRect.top - bodyRect.top;
}
```

Comment: Why you do the dot inside rotating div?

Comment: @Yukulélé It will be placed on rotating radar and it will be used to move object in my school project.

Answer (score 1):

For the mouse movement, it's a very simplified code using jQuery:

```
$('.wrapper, .outer').mousemove(function(e){ 
$('#light').css('left', e.pageX);
$('#light').css('top', e.pageY);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jre86rdd/30/

Tell me if this was what you wanted.

Edit: Also you need to move the light div outside of the wrapper class because it is affected by your CSS

Comment: Sry, i asked wrong question. I need to make dragable dot (that's why it needs to follow cursor.) But that dot after dragend will have to move with div undearneath it.

Answer (score 0):

With your new comment, this is my answer:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="outer">
     <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dot" id="light"></div>
```

JS:

```
var timeout;
var down = false;
var inside = 0; //Not a boolean because .outer can trigger false when .wrapper is true

$(document).mousedown(function() {
    down = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
    down = false;  
}).mouseleave(function() {
    down = false;  
});

$('.wrapper, .outer').mouseenter(function(){
    inside++;
}).mouseleave(function() {
    inside--;
});

$('#light').mousedown(function () {
    var x, y;
    timeout = setInterval(function () {
        if(down){   
            $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
                x = event.pageX;
                y = event.pageY;
            });           
            if (inside > 0){
                $('#light').css('left', x - 5);
                $('#light').css('top', y - 5);
            }
         }
         else
        {
             clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    }, 20);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jre86rdd/124/

Comment: Still, when i rotate it, the dot changes in position in relation to divs. Maybe i should completely change my aproach and instead of rotating whole div, "rotate" the dot?

Comment: Have you changed the html? The dot need to be outside of the inner/outer/wrapper class